# commutative ring which have every maximal ideal generated by an idempotent

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, idempotents

Can you help me with one example of commutative ring which have every maximal ideal generated by an *idempotent*?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203683/proving-a-ring-is-noetherian-when-all-maximal-ideals-are-principal-generated-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following (non-trivial?) example: $R=\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$?

One can prove the following:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring such that all its maximal ideals are generated by an idempotent, then $R$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields.

For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203683/proving-a-ring-is-noetherian-when-all-maximal-ideals-are-principal-generated-by).

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a field. then its only maximal ideal is $0.$

---

[A ring is semisimple if and only if every right (or every left) ideal is generated by an idempotent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_element) If you want to know semisimple rings, note that [a ring is semisimple if and only if it is Artinian and its Jacobson radical is zero.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings)

Comment: Non trivial ...

Comment: [A ring is semisimple if and only if every right (or every left) ideal is generated by an idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_element)

Comment: a finite direct sum of fields is an example?

Comment: examples are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings). you can see there: **A commutative semisimple ring is a finite direct product of fields**